# Is this the REST compliance way of showing image?

Tags: java, ruby, rest

I have designed a image processing API for my colleague. He is using Ruby (RestClient) as client.

```
$ curl -i -X GET http://abc.com:8080/api/v0/compare-19
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2013 08:02:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Location: http://abc.com:8080/result/856caf71-df10-4b9e-a981-4785de2f4854.png
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(8.1.3.v20120416)

{
    "id": 19,
    "state": "completed",
    "timestamp": "2013-01-10T00:01:13.755-08:00",
    "resultImage": "856caf71-df10-4b9e-a981-4785de2f4854.png",
    "passcode": "AXBD"
}
```

He wanted to capture "state" and "passcode", however according to RESTClient documentation, ruby program redirected to http://abc.com:8080/result/856caf71-df10-4b9e-a981-4785de2f4854.png immediately.

```
Exceptions (see www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)
for results code between 200 and 207 a RestClient::Response will be returned
for results code 301, 302 or 307 the redirection will be followed if the request is a get or a head
for result code 303 the redirection will be followed and the request transformed into a get
for other cases a RestClient::Exception holding the Response will be raised, a specific exception class will be thrown for know error codes
```

My question is, is this the right way to give REST response?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you just left the URL at `http://abc.com:8080/api/v0/compare-19` to be a 200 OK response without the redirect. Have the response's resultImage be a relative/absolute URL to the image. Then clients can get the metadata about the operation and follow the resultImage URL if they want to get the final result image.